# Switching JPanel within JApplet

Tags: java, event-handling, jpanel, japplet

here is the question. I have a JApplet, and inside the applet I have two JPanels, panel1 and panel2. Each panel has a label shown "panel1" or "panel2", and each panel has a button called "switch". When I run the applet, I only want panel1 to be visible. And when I click the switch button, I wanna panel1 to be invisible (or disappear) and panel2 to be visible. I will also want to click the switch button in panel2 to switch back to panel1. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public class MyApplet extends JApplet
{
    private Panel1 panel1;
    private Panel2 panel2;

    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        panel1 = new Panel1();
        panel2 = new Panel2();

        add(panel1);
        //add(panel2);
    }
}

public class Panel1 extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public Panel1()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Panel1");
        button = new JButton("Switch1");

        add(label);
        add(button);
    }
}

public class Panel2 extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel label;
    private JButton button;

    public Panel2()
    {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Panel2");
        button = new JButton("Switch2");

        add(label);
        add(button);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a "content" to the applet, where you want to switch panels in and out off.

Set this panels layout manager to `CardLayout`

Add your other panels to the "content" pane

```
content.add(aPanel, "PanelA");
content.add(bPanel, "PanelB");
```

Use the CardLayout API to switch the panels...

```
cardLayout.show(content, "PanelB");
```

Have a read through [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks, but is there any way to do this without cardlayout?

Comment: [`Container#remove`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#remove%28java.awt.Component%29) and [`Container#add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29)

Comment: *"..is there any way to do this without cardlayout?"*  Is there any reason **not** to use `CardLayout`?  It is always handy to add the 'why' to the 'what' in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Add them both to the applet, and setVisible(false) on one of them.

Add listeners for the buttons.

The listeners will toggle the setVisible of the appropriate panel.

Comment: the problem is that the button is inside the panel. I can set the panel itself to invisible for sure, but how I can set the other panel to be visible?

Comment: See the CardLayout thing above. The panels stack on top of each other like cards.